# Wrong number or types of arguments error while calling procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error, procedure

How can i call procedure inside another procedure in Oracle?I'm trying as follow but i am getting that error "PLS-00306 (325: 13): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TITLE_CRUD'"

```
PROCEDURE create_title(
        P_TITLE varchar2,
        P_USER varchar2,
        P_ERR OUT VARCHAR2 
   )
   IS    
   BEGIN  
        IF P_TITLE IS NULL THEN
            P_ERR := 'Null value';
        ELSE
            title_crud('I',NULL,P_TITLE,P_USER);      
        END IF;  
   END;


 PROCEDURE title_crud(
        P_OP_TYPE VARCHAR2,
        P_ID number,
        P_TITLE varchar2,
        P_USER varchar2,
        P_ERR OUT VARCHAR2 
   )...
```

Comment: In the call to title_crud you have defined 4 parameters but you need one to hold the P_ERR OUT out variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the change below, the call to `title_crud` doesn't have a variable to hold what is being returned by it (p_err)

```
PROCEDURE create_title(
        P_TITLE varchar2,
        P_USER varchar2,
        P_ERR OUT VARCHAR2 
   )
   IS    
   BEGIN  
        IF P_TITLE IS NULL THEN
            P_ERR := 'Null value';
        ELSE
            title_crud('I',NULL,P_TITLE,P_USER,P_ERR); -- Extra Parameter      
        END IF;  
   END;


 PROCEDURE title_crud(
        P_OP_TYPE VARCHAR2,
        P_ID number,
        P_TITLE varchar2,
        P_USER varchar2,
        P_ERR OUT VARCHAR2 
   )...
```

An easy mistake to make but I find easier to avoid when calling a procedure you pass parameters by named notation. Your call to title_crud becomes

```
...
 title_crud(P_OP_TYPE => 'I',
            P_ID      =>  NULL,
            P_TITLE   =>  P_TITLE,
            P_USER    =>  P_USER,
            P_ERR     =>  P_ERR);
...
```