# pls-00306 wrong number or types of arguments in call to procedure

Tags: plsql

Am new to PL SQL, How do i resolve the pls-00306 wrong number or types of arguments in call to procedure?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE overtime (
 Normal_Hours NUMBER ,
 Hours_worked NUMBER ,
 message VARCHAR2 ,
 Overtime IN OUT NUMBER )

AS  

 Begin
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ENTER HOURS WORKED' || &hours_worked);
     IF hours_worked <=Normal_Hours  THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO OVETIME WORKED');
 ELSE
     BEGIN
        Overtime := Hours_worked - Normal_Hours;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You have worked' || Overtime );
      END;
      END IF;
 END;
 /
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrong number or types of arguments error while calling procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449128/wrong-number-or-types-of-arguments-error-while-calling-procedure)

Comment: Do you get this error when calling `overtime` or when compiling `overtime`? Because `&hours_worked` might be the source, since the `&` may be taking user input at compile time and incorporating into the procedure causing weirdness.

Comment: Compilation does not give an error, error occurs when calling the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a procedure or a function, parameters declared should be consistent when the procedure or function is called.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE overtime (
Normal_Hours NUMBER ,
Hours_worked NUMBER ,
message VARCHAR2 ,
Overtime IN OUT NUMBER )
```

Since you have declared 4 parameters in your procedure, it is by the rule that when calling your procedure, you should also have 4 variables/values to pass.

```
declare
out_overtime number; -- this is the variable that will catch the value passed by the procedure

begin
overtime(8,9,'One Hour overtime', out_overtime);
dbms_output.put_line('Total overtime is '||out_overtime||' hours');
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help...i managed to do it another way though.

Answer (score 1):

Err ... Call the procedure with correct number and types of arguments ? E.g.

```
declare
  v_overtime number;
begin
  overtime(
    normal_hours => 8
   ,hours_worked => 12
   ,message      => 'clever message'
   ,overtime     => v_overtime
  );
  dbms_output.put_line(v_overtime);
end;
/
```

Note that because 4th argument's passing mode is `in out` you need to bind that into a variable - a constant won't do.